# Remove "Total" row from Netsuite summary saved search

Tags: oracle, search, netsuite, erp

I have a saved search with group and summed entries. I want to export them to CSV but I don't want a row for the total. Is there any way to remove this? It seems to appear by default for summarized searches regardless of whether or not "Show Totals" is checked.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to produce summed results without using the "Sum" summary type. If you use a formula field, you can include "SUM" as part of the formula, summarize using the "Maximum" summary type, and get the same results without seeing the Totals row.

---

Creating a Saved Search results column with the following gets you summarized "Amount" values, but results in a Totals row:

**FIELD:** Amount

**SUMMARY TYPE:** Sum

---

The following formula will result in the same summarized "Amount" values, but will not prompt a Totals row from NetSuite:

**FIELD:** Formula (Currency)

**SUMMARY TYPE:** Maximum

**FORMULA:** SUM({amount})